# JPA is not executing any query

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm Stuck with JPA since two days , im trying to save a new Object to database but i got no luck with it, it's just throw no exception so i don't know what is going on. why my code is not working
here is the controller

```
@RestController
public class RealEstatesViewController {
    @Autowired
    private RealEstateRepository realEstatesViewRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/realEstatesView", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addRealEstatesClass(@RequestBody ArrayList<RealEstatesView> realEstatesViews)
            throws Exception {
        realEstatesViewRepository.save(realEstatesViews);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

here is my Model i implemented my columns with my tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "real_estates_views")
public class RealEstatesView {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name = "real_estate_view_id")
    private int realEstateViewId;
    @Column(name = "real_estate_offer_id")
    private int realEstateOfferId;
    @Column(name = "real_estate_view_date")
    private String realEstateViewDate;
    @Column(name = "real_estate_view_time")
    private String realEstateViewTime;

}
```

here is my repo

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.akarat.demo.model.RealEstatesView;

@Repository
public interface RealEstateRepository extends CrudRepository<RealEstatesView, Integer> {

}
```

and my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AkaratDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AkaratDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Akarat</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

finally the resource folder

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/demo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: What is the exception and stack trace?

Comment: try profiling your application, Im willing to bet there is an error

Comment: How the repo look like?

Comment: Are you sure your list of items has a primary key? I think save will insert if no previous state is detected or update if there is. I also think you need to provide a primary key. Is there a stack trace you can provide or a some SQL?

Comment: @RobertFarley there is no exception

Comment: @JohnKane there is no error in the log

Comment: @HRgiger check the updated question please

Comment: @SamOrozco Yep im completely sure of it

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens and what is expected? What is the console output? What is the request body in the controller? Do you receive the empty 200 response? How are you verifying that the database state is not what you expect?

Comment: @RobertFarley still didn't make any validation , there is no console output and no exceptions that is so strange i hope that there is an exception so that i can solve the problem

Comment: Im wondering if your logs are configured correctly? and did you try running a profiler?

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/

Comment: private int realEstateViewId; -> Do you have a row in your database with id 0? Since you can not have null id you might be updating same row

Comment: @HRgiger it's integer in database